# Cron job is not running as per the scheduled time using Golang

Tags: go, cron

I am implementing the scheduler job using Golang but  its not working as expected. I am explaining my code below.

```
c := cron.New()
    //c.AddFunc("*/1 * * * *", func() { fmt.Println("Every hour on the one minute") })
    c.AddFunc("@every 0h1m0s", func() { 
        fmt.Println("Every minute");
        if cronService.CheckConnection() {
            fmt.Println("Internet connected")
            //cronService.SyncOrder()
        } else {
            fmt.Println("No Internet")
        }

    })

    c.Start()
    // Added time to see output
    time.Sleep(1 * (time.Second) * 60)

    c.Stop() // Stop the scheduler (does not stop any jobs already running).
```

Here I trying to run my scheduler job  in each 1 min but in my case its running once only after my server started. Here I need after started server the cron job should run in each 1 min always.

Comment: You're stopping the server after one minute, why do you expect it to execute a `@every 0h1m0s` job more than once in a single minute?

Comment: https://play.golang.com/p/ZdSe4lmxpAn